# Script to Move files one at a time and rename

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a requirement to move *.csv files from Europe to a server located in North America where a service is listening to process the files as they arrive.

The issue I am having is on occasion the listener on the server will pick up the file as it being dropped and will attempt to process it and fail.

What I have been advised to do is move the file as .txt then rename it immediately when it appears in the destination directory. This works fine but I now need to automate this process for many files.

Note the listener service will also stop if too many files are renamed at once.

In simple terms

```
For Each *.txt in Folder c:\Source
  Move from  C:\Source to \\ne-ifs-app\IN_FIELD_SERVICE\
  Rename \\ne-ifs-app\IN_FIELD_SERVICE\*.txt *.csv
Repeat for next File
```

Comment: The logic of your pseudocode seems fine. What is your actual problem? Given the _listener service will also stop if too many files are renamed at once_ I suggest using a sleep in the loop so slow to process of renaming down. How long? You will have to test to be sure. Do you have actual code to show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do:

Set your variables of the current path, the new path and where you get your stuff:

```
$FirstPath = "C:\Source\"
$NewPath = "\\ne-ifs-app\IN_FIELD_SERVICE\"
$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "$FirstPath\*.txt" | select name, fullname
```

Now take each item from `$Stuff` and move it to your new path, rename the file at its new location, then wait 10 seconds to do it to the next file in `$Stuff`:

```
ForEach($I in $Stuff){
  $newfile = $NewPath + $I.name
  $newname = $newfile -Replace "txt","csv"
  Move-Item $I.fullname $NewPath
  Rename-Item $Newfile $newname -Force
  Start-Sleep -s 10
}
```

That should take care of that.

Comment: Nate - Your a legend, Works perfectly,

Comment: I just want to help.  Please accept this as the answer so it falls off the list.  Happy coding, friend.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the snippet.

I had a similar task, but needed to first rename the file, then move it, then change extension back to the original one.

Here is what I ended up with (I have never worked with PS code before and have limited knowledge of coding in general, so sorry for the sloppiness).

=====

```
$FirstPath = "C:\0001\"
$NewPath = "C:\0002\"
$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "$FirstPath\*.txt" | select name, fullname

ForEach($I in $Stuff){
  $curname = $I.name
  $modname = $curname -Replace "txt","csv"
  $CurFile = $FirstPath + $curname
  $newname = $FirstPath + $modname
  Rename-Item $CurFile $newname -Force
  Move-Item $newname $NewPath
  $NewFile = $NewPath + $modname
  $origname = $NewPath + $curname
  Rename-Item $NewFile $origname -Force
  Start-Sleep -s 1
}
```

=====